# Sort based on third column numerically and then last character of first column (non-fixed length) alphanumerically without a fixed delimiter in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed

I am trying to sort a text file with third columns based on first the third column numerically and then the last character of the first column. Here is an example:

```
AB2 S 12
ABRT6 E 23
A3 S 2
ABC5 E 34
ABRT4 S 23
```

The expected output should be:

```
A3 S 2
AB2 S 12
ABRT4 S 23
ABRT6 E 23
ABC5 E 34
```

I looked into the related questions but all of them assume the length of the numeric part in the first column has a fixed index or there is a known delimiter between characters and numbers in the first column. Right now I am trying the following command but it fails to sort based on the first column when third columns are the same. Any suggestion?

```
sort -k3,3n -k1,1
```

Comment: Use `awk` to add another column that contains the last character of the first column. Pipe that to `sort`, then pipe it to `cut` to remove the extra column.

Comment: Unless it is just me, your sample data is not compelling; your `sort -k3,3n -k1,1` generates the desired output.  If you added an entry `ABBT9 X 23`, then the `ABBT9` entry would sort before `ABRT4`, but you would really want it to appear afterwards because the trailing digit 9 comes after the trailing digit 4.  Is that correct?  If so, I think that 'just sort' won't help because it doesn't have a concept similar to 'negative column offsets' which could be used: `-k1.-1,1.-1`.  Such a notation could be added — but you'd have to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed` to insert a space before the last charactert, then sort, and use `sed` again to remove the inserted space:

```
sed 's/\(.\) / \1 /' input \
| sort -k4,4n -k2,2 \
| sed 's/ //'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gnu-awk command that does it in single command using `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"} {a[$3,substr($1, length($1), 1)] = $0}
     END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
A3 S 2
AB2 S 12
ABRT4 S 23
ABRT6 E 23
ABC5 E 34
```

- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"` sets default order of awk array as numeric indices.
- `a[$3,substr($1, length($1), 1)]=$0` populates array using composite key as 3rd column and last char of 1st column. Value is `$0`.
- In the `END` block we just loop through the array and print the value part (full row).

Answer (score 0):

@choroba's solution is smart, here is another solution using `cut`s.  Uses `rev` to get the last character.

```
$ paste file <(cut -d' ' -f1 file | rev | cut -c1) \
           | sort -k3n                             \
           | cut -f1

A3 S 2
AB2 S 12
ABRT4 S 23
ABRT6 E 23
ABC5 E 34
```